# JBoss 7.1.1 localhost:8080 unable to connect

Tags: java, jboss, jboss7.x

This is the first time I try to run jboss. I've downloaded jboss-as-7.1.1.Final.zip and tried to run jboss standalone.sh from root user (all jboss files also belong to root). But when I tried to open http://127.0.0.1:8080/ or http://0.0.0.0:8080/ or http://localhost:8080/ I always get **unable to connect**. And `netstat -na | grep 8080` always returns nothing.

Also I've configured next variables in **/root/.bashrc**:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/jboss/jre1.8.0_171
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export JBOSS_HOME=/jboss/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final
```

So they are:

```
echo $JAVA_HOME; echo $JBOSS_HOME; echo $PATH
/jboss/jre1.8.0_171
/jboss/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final
/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/jboss/jre1.8.0_171/bin:/jboss/apache-maven-3.6.0/bin
```

I tried to run `sh standalone.sh` and `sh standalone.sh -b 0.0.0.0` but nothing has changed.

I tried to change **standalone/configuration/standalone.xml**:

```
<interfaces>
        <interface name="management">
            <any-address/>
        </interface>
        <interface name="public">
            <any-address/>
        </interface>
        <interface name="unsecure">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.unsecure:127.0.0.1}"/>
        </interface>
    </interfaces>
```

but again... nothing has changed.

logs from standalone/log/boot.log:

```
18:10:36,349 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.1.5.GA
18:10:36,478 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.2.GA
18:10:36,523 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015899: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" starting
18:10:36,524 DEBUG [org.jboss.as.config] Configured system properties:
    [Standalone] = 
    awt.toolkit = sun.awt.X11.XToolkit
    file.encoding = UTF-8
    file.encoding.pkg = sun.io
    file.separator = /
    java.awt.graphicsenv = sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment
    java.awt.headless = true
    java.awt.printerjob = sun.print.PSPrinterJob
    java.class.path = /jboss/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/jboss-modules.jar
    java.class.version = 52.0
    java.endorsed.dirs = /jboss/jre1.8.0_171/lib/endorsed
    java.ext.dirs = /jboss/jre1.8.0_171/lib/ext:/usr/java/packages/lib/ext
    java.home = /jboss/jre1.8.0_171
    java.io.tmpdir = /tmp
    java.library.path = /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
    java.net.preferIPv4Stack = true
    java.runtime.name = Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
    java.runtime.version = 1.8.0_171-b11
    java.specification.name = Java Platform API Specification
    java.specification.vendor = Oracle Corporation
    java.specification.version = 1.8
    java.util.logging.manager = org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager
    java.vendor = Oracle Corporation
    java.vendor.url = http://java.oracle.com/
    java.vendor.url.bug = http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/
    java.version = 1.8.0_171
    java.vm.info = mixed mode
    java.vm.name = Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
    java.vm.specification.name = Java Virtual Machine Specification
    java.vm.specification.vendor = Oracle Corporation
    java.vm.specification.version = 1.8
    java.vm.vendor = Oracle Corporation
    java.vm.version = 25.171-b11
    javax.management.builder.initial = org.jboss.as.jmx.PluggableMBeanServerBuilder
    javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory = __redirected.__DatatypeFactory
    javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory = __redirected.__DocumentBuilderFactory
    javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory = __redirected.__SAXParserFactory
    javax.xml.stream.XMLEventFactory = __redirected.__XMLEventFactory
    javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory = __redirected.__XMLInputFactory
    javax.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactory = __redirected.__XMLOutputFactory
    javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory = __redirected.__TransformerFactory
    javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory:http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema = __redirected.__SchemaFactory
    javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory:http://java.sun.com/jaxp/xpath/dom = __redirected.__XPathFactory
    jboss.home.dir = /jboss/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final
    jboss.host.name = xxxxx
    jboss.modules.dir = /jboss/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/modules
    jboss.modules.system.pkgs = org.jboss.byteman
    jboss.node.name = xxxxx
    jboss.qualified.host.name = xxxxx
    jboss.server.base.dir = /jboss/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone
    jboss.server.config.dir = /jboss/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/configuration
    jboss.server.data.dir = /jboss/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/data
    jboss.server.default.config = standalone.xml
    jboss.server.deploy.dir = /jboss/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/data/content
    jboss.server.log.dir = /jboss/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/log
    jboss.server.name = xxxxx
    jboss.server.temp.dir = /jboss/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/tmp
    line.separator = 

    logging.configuration = file:/jboss/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/configuration/logging.properties
    module.path = /jboss/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/modules
    org.jboss.boot.log.file = /jboss/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/log/boot.log
    org.jboss.resolver.warning = true
    org.xml.sax.driver = __redirected.__XMLReaderFactory
    os.arch = amd64
    os.name = Linux
    os.version = 3.10.0-862.14.4.el7.x86_64
    path.separator = :
    sun.arch.data.model = 64
    sun.boot.class.path = /jboss/jre1.8.0_171/lib/resources.jar:/jboss/jre1.8.0_171/lib/rt.jar:/jboss/jre1.8.0_171/lib/sunrsasign.jar:/jboss/jre1.8.0_171/lib/jsse.jar:/jboss/jre1.8.0_171/lib/jce.jar:/jboss/jre1.8.0_171/lib/charsets.jar:/jboss/jre1.8.0_171/lib/jfr.jar:/jboss/jre1.8.0_171/classes
    sun.boot.library.path = /jboss/jre1.8.0_171/lib/amd64
    sun.cpu.endian = little
    sun.cpu.isalist = 
    sun.io.unicode.encoding = UnicodeLittle
    sun.java.command = /jboss/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/jboss-modules.jar -mp /jboss/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/modules -jaxpmodule javax.xml.jaxp-provider org.jboss.as.standalone -Djboss.home.dir=/jboss/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final
    sun.java.launcher = SUN_STANDARD
    sun.jnu.encoding = UTF-8
    sun.management.compiler = HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers
    sun.os.patch.level = unknown
    sun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval = 3600000
    sun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval = 3600000
    user.country = US
    user.dir = /jboss/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/bin
    user.home = /root
    user.language = en
    user.name = root
    user.timezone = Europe/xxxxx
18:10:36,530 DEBUG [org.jboss.as.config] VM Arguments: -D[Standalone] -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+TieredCompilation -Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djboss.server.default.config=standalone.xml -Dorg.jboss.boot.log.file=/jboss/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/log/boot.log -Dlogging.configuration=file:/jboss/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/configuration/logging.properties
```

My console:

```
=========================================================================

  JBoss Bootstrap Environment

  JBOSS_HOME: /jboss/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final

  JAVA: /jboss/jre1.8.0_171/bin/java

  JAVA_OPTS:  -server -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+TieredCompilation -Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djboss.server.default.config=standalone.xml

=========================================================================

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
18:10:36,349 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.1.5.GA
18:10:36,478 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.2.GA
18:10:36,523 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015899: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" starting
```

What else can I do? Just any idea to continue the search for the reasons....

Comment: As you can see from the console output, the server is `starting`, not `started`. Does it hang there?

Comment: yes, it's the last string from output.

Comment: WTH are you even using a version of JBoss that old now? It's ancient, you should really be using the latest versions of Wildfly instead, for security reasons if nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your standalone.xml (considering your JBoss is started):

```
    <interfaces>
        <interface name="management">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:127.0.0.1}"/>
        </interface>
        <interface name="public">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.1}"/>
        </interface>
        <interface name="unsecure">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.unsecure:127.0.0.1}"/>
        </interface>
        <interface name="any">
            <any-address/>
        </interface>
    </interfaces>
```

Comment: It was in a first version of the standalone.xml. And as I wrote, It doesn't work. But to be sure, I've copied that to standalone.xml and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Federico klez Culloca. I tried to find why I got `starting`, not `started`. And found:
https://developer.jboss.org/thread/238565

*"AS7.1 does not work on JDK8."*  => So I installed jdk1.7.0_80 and it helps. I can open http://localhost:8080 in a browser and `netstat -na | grep 8080`returns:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8080          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

Comment: I tried both variants of standalone.xml (from my question and from @jhenrique answer). They both work.